# ASP.NET MVC 5 - create own login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Hy,

I'm very new to MVC 5 (or any other MVC). I want to create my own custom login with registration. Can somebody point me to this?

The login should have a simple email and password textbox. The registration should have additional data like first/lastname, age, etc. which stored in a table (user) and a dropdownbox with roles to select (stored in table "roles"). After successful login/registration should the user be redirected to the dashboard.

Or is there a good tutorial about this for MVC 5 .. I just found one for [MVC 4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/482546/Creating-a-custom-user-login-form-with-NET-Csharp).

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Your question is kind of broad. Please read [ask]. What do you want this custom login with registration to do? Does it store additional information upon registration? Does it redirect somewhere? Does it dance?

Comment: @Jack The login should just have an email and password textbox. The registration should have additional information like first/lastname, age, etc. - this data should be stored in a table named "user" (in a MS SQL Server 2012). The registration should have one special data: a role dropdownbox, where the user can choose his role .. this will be stored in a other table (roles). If the user has registered successful he should be redirect to the dashboard. When a user has successful loged in, also a redirect should be done to the dashboard.

Comment: @Jack I think, that's nothing special .. but I don't know how I should code this. I just only have expience with plain PHP :(

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = MyViewModels.checkUser(model.UserName, model.Password);
        if (user!=null)
        {
            SignInAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Welcome");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}

private void SignInAsync()
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>();
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "UserName"));
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "User@mail.com"));
    var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,
                                DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
    var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
    authenticationManager.SignIn(id);
}

[Authorize]
public ActionResult Welcome()
{
    return View();
}
```

If you add [Authorize] attribute in the action, then it will redirect only the user name and password is authorize

Function to get user name and password from database

```
public static UserTable checkUser(string userName, string password)
{
    DemoEntities db = new DemoEntities();
    var query = (from u in db.UserTables
                 where u.UserName == userName && u.Password == password
                 select u).FirstOrDefault();
    if(query!=null)
        return query;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: The type or namespace name 'UserTable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: @WIRN, UserTable is a table name from the database. This table is accessed from entity frame work